# react-native-maps other Markers visible on Tooltip - iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

On iOS Markers are Visible on Tooltip. I think Tooltip should be always on the top. Did I missed something, or it is a popular issue in react-native-maps ?

```
  <_MapView
    style={[{flex: 1}, this.props.style]}
    showsPointsOfInterest={true}
    region={region}
    {...this.props}
  >
    {annotations.map((marker, ind) => (

      <_MapView.Marker
        key={ind}
        image={marker.image}
        coordinate={marker.latlng}
        ref={ref => { this.markers[ind] = ref }}
        onPress={() => {
          if (this.activeMarker) {
            this.activeMarker.closeCallout()
          }
          this.markers[ind].showCallout()
        }}
      >
        <_MapView.Callout style={StyleSheet.mapView.callOut} onPress={marker.rightCalloutView}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            underlayColor="transparent"
          >
            <View style={StyleSheet.mapView.toolTip}>
              <Text>{marker.title}</Text>
              <View>
                <Icon name="chevronRight" />
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </_MapView.Callout>
      </_MapView.Marker>
    ))}
  </_MapView>
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: As I am unable to upload images yet , however this is an link to image. https://bitbucket.org/knwn/hoops/issues/attachments/73/knwn/hoops/1495498761.81/73/Screen%20Shot%202017-05-23%20at%2001.17.54.png // Thanks for respond

Comment: please do upload it on imgur or something public i am getting an " Access denied "

Comment: http://imgur.com/9pzx7IH

Comment: Sorry my friend, forgot that it was on bitbucket